# If, Else statement in Javascript not working. Is what I am doing even possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JSfiddle (showing the non-working code) here: http://jsfiddle.net/ts2Rr/

I have three boxes that a user must click one at a time to see the content of that box. Upon seeing the content of that box the user inputs text into a textbox and then the next box is shown. However, the user only has five seconds to do so. Testing the code so far seems to indicate that the failure occurs around the if else statement but I can't figure out what's wrong. Without the if else statement in the code, everything works up to that point. With the if else statement in the code nothing works (not even the code before it).

With the if else statement I am trying to use two variables (one set upon the start of the function, and the other set when the user inputs text). I then subtract the two to get a millisecond time variable. If that is less than 5,000 ms record it to the hidden form field. Else, run a setTimeOut function that records 5 seconds to the hidden form field. Is this even possible?

```
//start after 3 seconds on page load
   //settimeout()
         //appends onclick onto #Box 1 that calls function Rate when clicked
         //.toggleclass onto  #Box1
         //300;

window.onload = function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('#BoxE1').bind('click', function() {
                Rate();
                //alert('User clicked on "foo."');                    //uncomment for testing purposes only
            });
        $('#BoxE1').toggleClass('inactive active');
     }, 3000);
};

function Rate() {
    $('#E1Rate').show();                            //Show the object to be rated
    $('#BoxE1').unbind('click');                    //Prevent the user from clicking on the box again
    $('#BoxE1').toggleClass('inactive active');        //Toggles the box back to green
//Code works up to this point so far, if I need to rollback just add }; to the next line
    var startTime = new Date();
    var elaspedTime = (inputTime - startTime);         //Calculate the elasped milliseconds
    if (elaspedTime < 5000) {
        document.getElementById("E1RatingTime").value=elaspedTime;
    }
    else {
        setTimeout (function(){
            document.getElementById("E1RatingTime").value="5";
        }, 5000);
    }
    $('#E1Rate').hide();    
};
```

Comment: -1 because it doesn't look like you tried to solve this yourself but rather preferred to throw it all on us and hope for quick help. You **already have** valid and working `setTimeout` in your code so it's not like it's something new to you.

Comment: It didn't dawn upon me to check the setTimeout function since I had thought I copied and pasted it from the above section. But even after that statement is fixed I still can't figure out why the if else function isn't working. I think it's something to do with the variable setting in the body (a keypress event that's fired) although it looks correct to me. What I'm wondering is what I'm trying to do even possible. Or if the if function is waiting on a un-set variable (inputTime) does it just sit there waiting, preventing the else statement from firing.

Comment: Your original code was simply a mess. If now after it's less messy it still doesn't work it's different matter but it does not change what I said before sorry.

Comment: no ways to improve your code on your own simply copy&paste and wait for us to do your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code stops working because of a syntax error in

```
SetTimeout function(){
```

Correct it to

```
setTimeout(function() {...}, 5000);
```

Btw. `getElementById()` does not need the # hash before the id string. It even won't work with the #

Comment: And there is no valid reason to use getElementById at all when you have jQuery available. The same applies to `window.onload` by the way.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the two problems you mentioned. The part that was working before works again. Although I don't think the if else statement works still since it shows the cat, and just stays there. What should be happening is that when a user inputs text an keypress event is fired to set the variable to the date (this JS is in the body)      `<script>
     $('#E1Rating').keyup(function() {
      var inputTime = new Date();
     });
     </script>`. But nothing happens. Not even the else statement fires.

Comment: with `var inputTime` you define and set a _local_ variable that will not be visible outside of the anonymous function in the keyup event handler!

Comment: Ah, so that's why it isn't working. That means I should a set a global variable. Thanks devnull69!